# Web.config transform removes first setting despite name locator

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2015, web-config, web.config-transform

I have a Web.config transform that is severely misbehaving. My web.config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>  </configSections>
  <appSettings>  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>  </system.web>
  <runtime>  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>  </entityFramework>
  <elmah>  </elmah>
  <applicationSettings>
    <MySite.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="CommandTimeout" serializeAs="String">
        <value>180</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LoginServerUrl" serializeAs="String">
        <value>mydevsite.com</value>
      </setting>
    </MySite.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

When I'd think that I should be able to get it with:

```
<MySite.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="LoginServerUrl" serializeAs="String" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
    <value>myqasite.com</value>
  </setting>
</MySite.Properties.Settings>
```

But when I do this, it replaces the first setting (command timeout) and leaves the second one there so that I have 2 loginserverurl settings and no command timeout!

The only way I can get it to transform mydevsite.com to myqasite.com is to create a transform that does this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" xdt:Transform="Replace">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Error404"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <applicationSettings>
    <MySite.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="LoginServerUrl" xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
      <setting name="CommandTimeout" xdt:Transform="Insert" serializeAs="String">
        <value>180</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LoginServerUrl" serializeAs="String" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
        <value>myqasite.com</value>
      </setting>
    </MySite.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Using your configuration (in an App.config file), the following (in an App.Debug.config file) worked perfectly for me:

The only thing I had to add was the `<applicationSettings>` tag to wrap `<MySite.Properties.Settings>`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- For more information on using app.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <applicationSettings>
    <MySite.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="LoginServerUrl" serializeAs="String" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
        <value>myqasite.com</value>
      </setting>
    </MySite.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

I'm using the "[Configuration Transformation](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859)" VS Extension to create the nested files for me:

[image: project file structure]

Comment: How did you check if it worked? Via preview transform on `App.Debug.config`?

Comment: @CBauer I looked at the outputted config file in the `bin\Debug` folder after a build